# Is Copenhagen bike share a good choice for a tourist?

Tags: transportation, bicycles, denmark, copenhagen

I am visiting Copenhagen for the first time and would primarily like to use a bike to get around since, as I understand, *that's what you do*. I found [Bycyklen](http://www.visitcopenhagen.com/copenhagen/bycyklen-gdk495345), which seems good because I won't need to worry about theft, and bike rental places can be kind of scummy in my experience. I have a Citi Bike membership and use it frequently in addition to my "real" bike so I'm familiar with bike share.

Is this a good way of getting around for a tourist? (for example, Citi Bike is a pretty big ripoff for non-annual members) Are there any caveats I should know about? (I once had a bad time getting an American credit card to work correctly with Velib)

Comment: Many municipalities, certainly including Copenhagen, have a free or almost free bicycle service, one can pick up a bike at designated spots and drop it at another designated spot.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Bycyklen For Tourists](https://bycyklen.dk/en/faq/for-tourists/) page, you can set up an account online before you arrive. A credit card is required, but because it's online and therefore doesn't require a chip, it should work with your US card.

The hourly rate is DKK 30, which is currently about US$4.50. Whether you would consider this a "ripoff" or not is up to you. There are also packages available to reduce the price.